# Application of DirectoryIndex to an Alias in Apache

Tags: apache, alias, directoryindex

How does one apply DirectoryIndex to an Alias in Apache without resulting in error 403?

This results in response header 200:

> `http://localhost/`  Which presents 
>   `http://localhost/index.html`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php index.xhtml index.htm default.htm
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
```

This results in error 403, forbidden:

> `http://localhost/aliasName/wwwrootDevelopmentSubDirectory/`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php index.xhtml index.htm default.htm
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    Alias /aliasName/ "/home/user/Dropbox/Level1/Level2/wwwrootDevelopment/"
    <Directory /home/user/Dropbox/Level1/Level2/wwwrootDevelopment>
            DirectoryIndex index.html index.php index.xhtml index.htm default.htm
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
```

error.log reveals same message seen in the browser.

```
[Tue Apr 02 00:19:30 2013] [error] [client 172.x.x.x] (13)Permission denied: access to /aliasName/wwwrootDevelopmentSubDirectory/ denied, referer: http://localhost/
```

Answer (score 0):

DirectoryIndex to an Alias  should be in pirticular directive  for that alias in apache2

```
Alias /pma "/var/www/pma"
<Directory "/var/www/pma">
    DirectoryIndex adminer.php
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
     AllowOverride All
     Require all granted
</Directory>
```