# Apache alias throws "You don't have permission to access" error

Tags: apache

Before posting, I looked at:

[You don't have permission to access / on this server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17442370/you-dont-have-permission-to-access-on-this-server)

[Application of DirectoryIndex to an Alias in Apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15756921/application-of-directoryindex-to-an-alias-in-apache)

As I understand it, the Alias directive allows documents to be stored in the local filesystem other than under the DocumentRoot.

Which is what I'm doing here.  I have a hello.php file in C:\Users\dogzilla\PhpstormProjects\Webpage

That's not my docroot... C:\Apache\latest\www is.

When I run the project, the URL sent from the IDE to the browser is

localhost:8080/Webpage/hello.php

Which leads to a 404 error.

But I don't want to dork around with the IDE settings more than I have so I added this to my httpd.conf.  I only grabbed "Webpage" because that's all which was in the URL when the 404 error was displayed.

Alias /Webpage C:/Users/dogzilla/PhpstormProjects/Webpage

When I re-ran my project, the 404 went away but the 403 error appeared.

So, in reading those two links above, I added this to httpd.conf too:

```
<Directory "C:/Users/dogzilla/PhpstormProjects/Webpage">
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

(Yeah, I'll tighten up security once this is running)

But I still get the 403 errors.

What am I doing wrong?  I've tried to RTFM.  Clearly I'm still doing something wrong.

Comment: @CBroe  Why do I "have" to do that?  Apache aliases are set up for EXACTLY the reason why I'm posting here in the first place.

Comment: You should add  `Options Indexes` to your directory permisions so in case your server doesn´t find the default files (index.html, index.php......), server return your directory. In case ` Options Indexes` is not implemented server return `403 Forbiden`                          
 - **You can see my full answers below**

Answer (score 5):

If you are creating an **Alias** to a directory **outside** of your **DocumentRoot**, you may need to explicitly **permit access** to the **target directory**.

```
Alias "/image" "/ftp/pub/image"
<Directory "/ftp/pub/image">
    Require all granted
    Options Indexes
</Directory>
```

If `Options Indexes` is not set, and no default files are find, server return a `403 status code` and will not show your directory.

Default files server will try to open are found in `httdd.conf`

```
<IfModule dir_module>
        DirectoryIndex index.php index.pl index.cgi index.asp index.shtml index.html index.htm \
                       default.php default.pl default.cgi default.asp default.shtml default.html default.htm \
                       home.php home.pl home.cgi home.asp home.shtml home.html home.htm
    </IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer... I was using 2.2 conf commands rather than 2.4. These links shed the light.  With the changes in httpd.conf between 2.2 and 2.4, I guess the moral of the story is to pay attention to the details:

https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/ClientDeniedByServerConfiguration

[Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21551840/forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-on-this-server)

Comment: Just for anyone else that comes along, in my case I had the Apache directives correct, but there was an `.htaccess` file blocking access.